# AlertDialog with EditText, wait for user response

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm designing function using AlertDialog to act like a InputBox in VB6. However using the code below, AlertDialog won't return values.

*Seems that the function returns before the user makes the input.*

```
public String InputBox(Context srcpage, String Msg, String Title, String InputDataType_TXT_or_NUM)
    {

        ResetReturnText();
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(srcpage);

        dlgAlert.setMessage(Msg);
        dlgAlert.setTitle(Title);

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText inputTxt = new EditText(srcpage);


        //Set the input type of the EditText
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        if(InputDataType_TXT_or_NUM=="TXT")
        inputTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);

        else if(InputDataType_TXT_or_NUM=="NUM")
        inputTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        else
        return "Invalid Data Type";
        //-------------------------------------------------------

        dlgAlert.setView(inputTxt);

        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          ReturnText = inputTxt.getText().toString();
          }
        });

        dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);
        dlgAlert.create().show();

        return ReturnText;
    }
```

I Want these code to return values with function calls like:

```
  String NewProvince="";
  NewProvince = InputBox(this, "Province:", "Add/Edit Province", "TXT");
  Log.w("Input:",NewProvince);
```

Can I ask you guys to help me with fixing this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems that Android can't block the UI model. Can anyone give me alternate solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a different approach, based on "callback".

So your function has simply to return `void` and do the stuff inside the onClick listener.

```
private void buildDialog() {
    // build your dialog with everything
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // do what you want with the value
            doSomethingWithValue(value);
        }
    });
}

protected void doSomethingWithValue(String value) {
    Log.i("MyTAG", value);
}
```

Comment: So I can't use this function is universal purpose, I mean where I can use it like vb6 InputBox? Or there is a method to call functions _dynamically_?

Comment: I don't have any experience in vb6 but you can build a function to handle the parameter and call it inside the onClick. In this way you can separate the two things. One is BUILDING the Dialog, the other is HANDLING the value. :)